# Spring Data what is the difference between @NamedQuery and @NamedNativeQuery?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am currently learning spring data can anyone explain what the difference between them `@NamedQuery` vs `@NamedNativeQuery` and When to use them?
Can we use native SQL in `@NamedQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@NamedNativeQuery` is for writing SQL query, while `@NamedQuery` is for writing HQL query.

So in your case, for writing native SQL query you would be needing `@NamedNativeQuery`.

However, be aware that writing native SQL will make your application less flexible and a portability nightmare because you are tying your application to work only for a particular database. If you are absolutely sure that you won't be needing to migrate to a different database, then this might not be a big concern for you. Otherwise prefer native HQL over native SQL.

Answer (score 2):

`@NamedQuery`is for writing your queries in JPQL, the standard query language of the JPA standard. This is the default and you should stick to these queries whenever possible, because they are independent of the exact DBMS which you use.

`@NamedNativeQuery` on the other hand is for writing native queries (in SQL) which potentially can be DBMS specific.

It is a tradeoff. `@NamedQuery` gives you portability because you stick to the standard. `@NamedNativeQuery` gives you flexibility but you leave the standard and potentially lose portability. In case you switch to another DBMS, it is likely you would need to rewrite some of your `@NamedNativeQuery` definitions.

So we should only use `@NamedNativeQuery` if it is really necessary.